# How to surcharge each credit card type, 2% for Visa & Master and 3% for Amex and Discover

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I can do the surcharge for payment method with selecting cc card or others, but when the buyer inserts his credit card number into cc-form, **I want that surcharge changes to 2% or 3% depends on credit card type.**
Please help me, thanks.

[image]

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-paymentfee This module applies a custom fee at selecting payment method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your module. That's excellent for the payment fee. But my question was after the chosen payment method to Credit Card. On the form for credit card information, when the customer input credit card number the rate should be changed 2% or 3% depends on the card's type.

Comment: @Y.Kim I've implemented the card type surcharge feature into the payment fee module suggested by Price Patel. However it is a bit complicated because each payment module needs to be customized to send the card type to the server. If you like I can send you a diff of my changes once I'm done. It may give you a better idea of how it can be implemented.

Comment: @micwallace - Yes I would like to have those diff of your changes on Prince's PaymentFee module for the same requirements

Comment: @Y.Kim - Were you able to find any workaround? I have a same requirement